# Why are corresponding USB datalines connected to each other in this USB hub?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, usb-hub

Background: this is (I think) effectively a USB hub, with built in ethernet. This is the circuit as it is being used in the Raspberry Pi B rev. 2

The USB+ from the upstream port (0) is connected to the USB+ on only one of the two downstream ports (3) through a 360R resistor [seen in the very middle of the image]. The USB- is similarly connected to the same downstream port (but the - line).

My questions - why is this being done, and why to that particular port? Could it be done to the other port (2), or both of them, or none?

[image: Segment of Raspberry Pi Schematic showing USB & Ethernet circuitry]

The datasheet for the LAN controller is here: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/9512.pdf

The whole schematic is here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Raspberry-Pi-R2.0-Schematics-Issue2.2_027.pdf

The part I have taken this image from is on page 3 of the schematic.

Comment: Good luck with DesignSpark PCB... Most awful electrical IDE I've used and yet the one I stick to because of experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an 0R resistor, a fittable link. It looks like on the Model A there's no hub and only a single port, which is connected straight through. On the model B the resistor is not fitted.

Comment: Thank you. I misread the schematic, of course the resistor value wouldn't wrap onto the next line!